# testng: how to design to run @test with multiple cases from dataprovider on different urls which are from another dataprovider?

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

Suppose I have a set of test cases, and I first open one url, and run the test:

```
@BeforeMethod
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void start(String browser) throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(url);

}
@Test(dataProvider = "TestA", dataProviderClass = xxx.class)
public void TestA(String VariableA1, String VariableA2..){

}

@Test(dataProvider = "TestB", dataProviderClass = xxx.class)
public void TestB(String VariableB1, String VariableB2..){

}

@Test(dataProvider = "TestC", dataProviderClass = xxx.class)
public void TestC(String VariableC1, String VariableC2..){

}
```

And I want to run the same set of test cases on different url which also stored in one of the table from the dataprovider. How can I design to achieve this logic?:

1. get a url urlX from the url table in the excel dataprovider.
2. run test: TestA, TestB, TestC.
3. then get url urlY from the url table in the excel dataprovider.
4. run test: TestA, TestB, TestC...
5. so on so forth..

How can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [TestNG factories](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories). e.g.

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DemoTest {
    private final String url;

    @Factory(dataProvider = "urls", dataProviderClass = xxx.class)
    public DemoTest(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "someData", dataProviderClass = DemoTest.xxx.class)
    public void something(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s, %d, %d", url, a, b));
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "someOtherData", dataProviderClass = DemoTest.xxx.class)
    public void somethingElse(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s, %d, %d", url, a, b));
    }

    public static class xxx {
        @DataProvider
        public static Iterator<Object[]> urls() {
            String[] urls = {
                    "https://www.google.com/",
                    "https://inbox.google.com/",
                    "https://calendar.google.com/",
                    "https://drive.google.com/"
            };
            return Arrays.stream(urls)
                    .map(s -> new Object[]{s})
                    .iterator();
        }

        @DataProvider
        public static Object[][] someData() {
            return new Object[][]{
                    {1, 2},
                    {3, 4}
            };
        }

        @DataProvider
        public static Object[][] someOtherData() {
            return new Object[][]{
                    {4, 3},
                    {2, 1}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
https://calendar.google.com/, 1, 2
https://calendar.google.com/, 3, 4
https://inbox.google.com/, 1, 2
https://inbox.google.com/, 3, 4
https://drive.google.com/, 1, 2
https://drive.google.com/, 3, 4
https://www.google.com/, 1, 2
https://www.google.com/, 3, 4
https://calendar.google.com/, 4, 3
https://calendar.google.com/, 2, 1
https://inbox.google.com/, 4, 3
https://inbox.google.com/, 2, 1
https://drive.google.com/, 4, 3
https://drive.google.com/, 2, 1
https://www.google.com/, 4, 3
https://www.google.com/, 2, 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I researched a bit about the TestNG factories, and was able to make it work. I implemented it slightly different from your solution.  I used excel as the dataprovider for both the @ factories and the @ test

Answer (score 0):

I implemented in the way below:

```
public class Test {
    WebDriver driver;
    private String hostName;
    private String url;


    @Factory(dataProvider = "xxxx global variables", dataProviderClass = globalxxx.class)
    public GetVariables(String hostName, String url, String GFlag) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.url = url;

    }

    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void start(String browser) throws Exception {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    }

    @Test(priority = 10, dataProvider = "dataprovider Test A", dataProviderClass = xxxA.class)
    public void TestA(Variable1,
            Variable2,Variable3) throws Exception {
        some test here...

    }

    @Test(priority = 20, dataProvider = "dataprovider Test B", dataProviderClass = xxxB.class)
    public void TestB(Variable1,
            Variable2,Variable3)
            throws Exception {
        some test here...
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
```